# While accessing the same angular 2 app on 2 different system ,when i scroll on 1 system, it gets scroll dat same page on another system automatically

Tags: angular

My question seems confusing, but pardon me , I am having this dilemma that,
I made an angular2 app, and am running the same app on two different system and while doing so, when I am accessing a page , scrolling it then that same page if opened on another system getting scrolled at the same time automatically.
I dont want my app to work like this.
I have provided a snapshot to support my question.

[Scrolling bar happening at the same time on another system for the same page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tp6uX.png)

P.S: I am beginner in Angular 2

Comment: your application seems to use `browsersync`, you have to remove that, if you are using it.

Comment: @Sravan Can you tell me how to remove it , I mean from which file I have to remove browsersync?

Comment: does your code has `npm` and `package.json` or `bower.json`, if yes check for `browser-sync` in `package.json ` or `bower.json`

Comment: @Sravan In package.json I have something like this :  "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0", "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0" but not exactly browser-sync term.

Comment: check for the same in `bower.json`, if you have `gulp`, check in `gulp.js` file

Comment: @Sravan In gulpfile.js , I found the browser sync term , what to do, should I remove that lline of code?

Comment: paste your gulp file here

Comment: In your browsersyc config set this part `ghostMode: {
                clicks: true,
                location: false,
                forms: true,
                scroll: true
            }` to all false depending on what you want.

Comment: @Sravan : Here is my file [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByS9FjwsQHpZdTlUQ28zU0dhZ3c/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @JoeKeene In which particular file you are telling me to change that part?

Comment: comment `browserSync({server: './app'});`

Comment: @Sravan Also I am confused there are alot gulpfile.js in different folders of my app, in which specific file you want me to remove browsersync?

Comment: @Nyki, I need the file where the server starts form

Comment: @Nyki like this browserSync({server: './app', ghostMode: {
        clicks: false,
        location: false,
        forms: false,
        scroll: false
    }});

Comment: @Nyki - hold on let me give you a full answer, that's not quite right.

Comment: @Sravan I tried to comment that line of code and then tested it, still the same problem is there

Comment: @Nyki, you might have the `browserSync` function some where in the code, search for it in the entire folder, and make the `ghostMode` false. check `server.js`, maybe `browsersync.js` etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `gulpfile.js` which you given the link.

Change the default task which has **`browserSync`** call.

Add the **`ghostMode: false`** as a new key and value.

**Then restart the server**

Change your `default gulp task`.

```
   var browserSync = require('browser-sync');


    gulp.task('default', function () {

        browserSync(
        {
            server: './app',
            ghostMode: false
        }
        );

        gulp.watch('./app/scss/*.scss', ['sass']);
        gulp.watch('./app/*.html',      ['html-watch']);
    });
```

Comment: I think you need the create and init on browser sync, docs on this can be found here https://browsersync.io/docs/gulp

Comment: This is just a snippet from the `gulpfile.js` from the question. The `browsersync` may have initialized somewhere else

Comment: @Sravan  After little much googling , I came to know that within node_module folder in my application, inside default.config.js file , set ghostMode:false.. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Think you need to do something like this, replace your `browserSync` call with the below and change init of browser sync. More options [here](https://browsersync.io/docs/options)

```
var browserSync = require("browser-sync").create();

gulp.task('default', function () {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./app",
            ghostMode: false
        }
    });

    gulp.watch('./app/scss/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('./app/*.html',      ['html-watch']);
});
```

Edit: You can just call false for ghost mode without setting each value.

Comment: After I made the changes you told me to, and restarted my server, still the problem is there, when checked on both systems for the same page , it is doing the same behaviour.. Help Me Out..!!

Comment: Apologies I didn't add the task etc, that should work in your gulpfile. Any idea which version of browser sync you have?